# Facebook Open Graph: Use of built in Read & Article type

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

How can I use the built in [Read Type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read) as a view OG for a non news site.
My pages are defined by a custom object type that is ***not an Article***.

Will this mean that I can add one more **type og:type 'article'** ?

To make it more clear lets say [Slideshare defines a custom OG type of](http://www.slideshare.net/ChristinUpshaw/learn-to-knit)

```
<meta name="og_type" property="og:type" class="fb_og_meta" content="slideshare:presentation" />
  <meta name="og_url" property="og:url" class="fb_og_meta" content="http://www.slideshare.net/ChristinUpshaw/learn-to-knit" />
  <meta name="og_image" property="og:image" class="fb_og_meta" content="http://image.slidesharecdn.com/learntoknit2-121024175526-phpapp02/95/slide-1-1024.jpg" />
  <!-- SL:start:notranslate -->
  <meta name="og_title" property="og:title" class="fb_og_meta" content="Learn to Knit!" />
  <meta name="og_description" property="og:description" class="fb_og_meta" content="Learn to knit with these resources.  All images found via Flickr Creative Commons search!" />
```

Now if slideshare wants to publish a **read OG**, should they create a new `og:type ‘article’` in the same page?

Will Facebook allow for 2 og:type's in the same page?

**How can I go about publishing views now that Facebook does not allow custom Reads anymore?**

Comment: _“Will Facebook allow for 2 og:type's in the same page?”_ – no, an Open Graph object can only be of one type.

Comment: It is also not permitted to create a custom 'read' action that would be generated by a user implicitly by using the site. With a suitably explicit action (for example the user clearly sharing the fact that they like this presentation), you can use a custom action. More information on explicit actions is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/explicit-sharing/

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to have more than 1 og:type. As described in the documentation it's only possible to refer the built-in "read"-action to an "article" og-type:

> For developers building apps in the News vertical, we have created the
>   built-in Read action that can only refer to the built-in Article
>   object type ([Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-actions/#read))

So, what you can do, to achieve this: Build an alternate view/url for your pages, which have the correct og:type "article" set up. Have a look at the Request Header/User Agent. If the term "facebook" isn't provided in the user agent, directly redirect the user to your main page. If "facebook" is part of the user agent, provide the alternate meta-tags on a blank page.